useRouteLoaderData returns undefined when we have error boundary in the root.tsx file in remix : v2.8.1
I have a loader in root.tsx and a component named 'Nav' which uses its loader data using useRouteLoderData hook. like const data = useRouteLoaderData('root') as any
 <body>
      <Nav/>
      <Layout>{children}</Layout>
      <ScrollRestoration />
      <Scripts />
      <LiveReload />
  </body>

this Nav component is in root because it should be there in all routes even in the error page.
How can i use the loader data inside my Nav component without it being undefined?
Let's say what I've tried so far:
I tried to use a DefaultErrorBoundary to catch the error in root.tsx but when i try to get the loader data from the Nav component. it becomes undefined.
My root loader looks like below:
export async function loader() {
  return defer(
    {
      navGraphql: await fetchGraphQL(navQuery),
      ENV: {
        STRAPI_URL: process.env.STRAPI_URL,
      },
    },
    {
      headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'public, s-maxage=300' },
    }
  )
}

here is the repo that implements the DefaultErrorBoundary.
https://github.com/kiliman/remix-root-errorboundary/tree/main
I'm puzzled as to why is the parent's loader data becoming undefined. and How to fix this?. Or has the approach been changed in my remix version?

Let us assume nothing goes wrong with the root.tsx,  how can i capture any error that comes in after my-domain-name.com. Should i capture the error in _index.tsx?

I solved this issue by having a global layout _main.tsx within this layout route all the other routes would render, rename _index.tsx as _main._index.tsx and so on for every other file.

Now inside the _main layout render rest of your routes using an Outlet Component from remix, Keep an error Boundary so it can capture the errors before it hits the root layout.
Note: Make sure the loader in your root.tsx does not Error out.
import { HeadersFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";
import {
    isRouteErrorResponse,
    useRouteError,
} from "@remix-run/react";

export default function MainLayout() {

    return (
        <>
            <Outlet /> // render rest of the routes
        </>
    );
}

export function ErrorBoundary() {
    const error = useRouteError(); //you can use this hook to make the message even more meaningful
    return (
        <main>
            Your Message to the User here
        </main>
    );
}

